# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Wordpress Health Check Issue

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a wordpress site running inside Elastic Beanstalk. My Health Checks are failing because of 3xx responses. I believe this is happening because the health check is trying to load the site using the ip of the ec2 instance. When the site is loaded wordpress checks the options table in the db and sends a redirect to the url listed under site_url.

In short, if I open a browser hit the ec2 instance directly by ip I get redirected to the actual url. I believe that is what is happening with the health check.

If this is the case how do I get the instances to respond with a 200 so the check passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I found out you can hit /wp-load.php this will run the wordpress engine and make sure everything is working properly but it will not return a 302 redirect